# R: Including a loop within a function?

Tags: r, function, foreach

Following code can be used to create a data.frame with Kendall-Tau and Spearman correlation results next to each other:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars

correlation <- function(x,y){
  df1 = cor(data.frame(x,y), use="complete.obs", method="kendall")
  df2 = cor(data.frame(x,y), use="complete.obs", method="spearman")
  return(data.frame(df1,df2))
}

correlation(mtcars[1],mtcars[2])
```

Question: Instead of chaining the commands, could something like a loop for the two method be implemented?

```
methods <- ("kendall", "spearman")

correlation <- function(x,y){
  df = cor(data.frame(x,y), use="complete.obs", method=methods)
  return(data.frame(df))
}

correlation(mtcars[1],mtcars[2])
#This should output the two results, just as above.
```

I tried a list but wasn't successful with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `for` statement.
Just do the following:

```
methods <- c("kendall", "spearman")

    correlation <- function(x,y, methods){

      result <- list()
      for (type in methods){

        df = cor(data.frame(x,y), use="complete.obs", method=type)

        result[type] <- list(df)
      }

      return(data.frame(result) )
    }

    correlation(mtcars[1],mtcars[2],methods)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this script. Error: unexpected ',' in "methods <- ("kendall","... When I make it a list, it still responds "argument "methods" is missing, with no default"

Comment: Corrected it, with the `c()`in the first line and passing 'methods' to the function, for me it is working now. Sorry forgot to adapt this.

Answer (score 0):

```
# vector that has your methods
methods <- c("kendall", "spearman")

# function which loops thru the vector of functions
correlation <- function(x,y) {
    a <- lapply(X = methods, FUN = function(m,x,y){
    df1 = cor(data.frame(x,y), use="complete.obs", method= m) 
  },x=x,y=y)

  return(a)
}

res <- correlation(mtcars[1],mtcars[2])
#list to dataframe 

do.call("cbind", lapply(res, as.data.frame))
```

The results :

```
           mpg        cyl        mpg        cyl
mpg  1.0000000 -0.7953134  1.0000000 -0.9108013
cyl -0.7953134  1.0000000 -0.9108013  1.0000000
```

Thanks!

Comment: Error in lapply(a, as.data.frame) : object 'a' not found?